# Parakaya Pravesh Technical Question Decomposition

Tags: shiva, adi-shankaracharya

When AdiShankar & Tirumular did parkaya-pravesh, they would leave their old body for quite some time. Same with Matsyendra & Gorakhnath, of the Nath Sampradaya.

Adi-Shankar left his body in a cave w/ disciples guarding it for like a month while he prepared for the debate with Bharati.

My question is, how does their old body not go into rotting/decaying ? They can leave their inert cast-off body for weeks and months then just get back into it and good to go ?

Plz excuse this is kinda gross question, who wants to think about rotting bodies and stuff. But I’m just curious how this works

Also, yeah, does anyone know when exactly Rajah VikramAditya did parkaya-pravesh ? What were the circumstances ? Ok thx guys (Happy Diwali btw :D)

Edit : Also Rajah Yayati did this as well, from what I understand.

Comment: you are ok with believing a person can leave their body and take another body, but have trouble believing they can keep their old body without rotting ?

Comment: @mar That’s legit. If they can leave their body and enter another one, they can probably easily keep stuff from going rotten. Yeah I’m overdoing it with logic here, obviously:D (I’m devibhakt btw. Going to change back to my original far-less-gringo username as soon the control panel thing on here lets me, in another coupla weeks.) :)